# Cannot import pygpu

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I am trying to import `pygpu` and I obtain the following:

```
>>> import pygpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/michele/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygpu/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import gpuarray, elemwise, reduction
ImportError: /home/michele/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygpu/gpuarray.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_Unpack
```

I have installed `python` through `anaconda` and everything seems to work fine. Can it be a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is described on their [Github](https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray/issues/421). They advice to reinstall 
*Pygpu* with conda-forge :

`conda remove pygpu && conda install -c conda-forge pygpu`

It doesn't work for me, maybe you'll be more lucky.